# What is causing the presence of a highlighted '%' in a new instance/new tab of a terminal window?

Tags: shell, command-line-interface, zsh

I recently did a quick customisation of my zsh prompt using the .zshrc file on my home directory. I noticed upon starting a new instance of every shell prompt, the presence of a highlighted '%' symbol on the very first line before the input line appears like so.

UPDATE 26/1/2022:

1. Update to a more accurate title reflecting the issue
2. I am using hyper.js CLI

[image: terminal screenshot]

I removed the customisation and it still appears so I am sure it has nothing to do with the .zshrc changes. What is causing the '%' sign to appear? It doesn't break anything functionally neither causing any frustration, just wondering as I am not super familiar with shells.

Comment: Does `starting a new instance of every shell prompt` mean a) every time you print the shell prompt in your current terminal window, e.g. after you hit "Enter", or b) only when you first start a new terminal window?

Comment: I mean b) starting a new terminal window, whether that be a completely new window or a new tab within the same window. the behaviour is the same for native Mac terminal and hyper.js which I am currently using.

Comment: OK, then it's not about your prompt it's about starting a new terminal. You might want to update your question, including the subject, to clarify that and state what terminal management software you use to open tabs/windows.

Comment: Just a wiild guess: Could it be that you have the variable `PROMPT_EOL_MARK` mark defined?

Comment: BTW, what happens if you create a **new login shell** in **the same terminal** window (i.e. as a child process)? How about when you create a **new non-login shell** in this way?

Comment: @user1934428 nope `PROMPT_EOL_MARK` is definitely not the case, I do not have this variable. not sure what the difference is between login and non-login shell, but any new terminal window or tab will encounter this.

Comment: Do as I recommended: Forget about new terminals and test it first with new subshells in the current terminal. One step after another!

Comment: For the difference between login- and nonlogin-shells, read the _zshall_ man page, in particular the section _STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES_ .  Also, some information on the topic is found in the _zshoptions_ man page. You can't reasonably configure your zsh (or bash, for that matter) if you don't know about the difference between those kinds of shell invocation. In short, you invoke a login subshell with `zsh -l` and a non-login subshell with just `zsh`.